# Cannot find SpriteFont template in Xna

Tags: c#, xna, spritefont

I'm trying to add a SpriteFont into my Content's folder for my Xna project, but I am unable to find the Sprite Font template and I'm now stuck.
I used MonoGame to get Xna working on VisualStudio 2012 and so far I have seen no differences.
What it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9An3.png

and what I'm getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wmc7.png

Answer (score 1):

MonoGame currently does not include the item templates for content. You need to install Windows Phone 8 SDK to get the item templates for content like SpriteFont. Additionally, you'll need to use a Windows Phone Content Project to compile your assets to XNB files, until the Build-time Content Pipeline is complete for MonoGame.